# Does beer cause more fatigue than liquor?

Tags: liquor

These days I drink almost as much liquor as I do beer, and it seems like beer more commonly causes sleepiness and fatigue, where liquor gives a straight up 'drunken' effect.

I wonder, though, is this actually the case or is my perception of the two drinks a self fulfilling prophecy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could definitely be a perception thing or any difference with the situation in which you consume beer vs liquor.  (IE, if you're drinking a lot of Jack and Coke maybe that caffeine is helping keep you alert?)

I think the most compelling answer is that there's actually a decent amount of research that shows hop compounds actually have a slightly sedative effect, especially in conjunction with alcohol.  So...you know, beer.

Some sources:

[National Institute of Health](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22849837): The concentration of 2 mg of hop extract effectively decreased nocturnal activity in the circadian activity rhythm.

[WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-856-hops.aspx?activeingredientid=856&activeingredientname=hops) (Look under "Interactions"): Alcohol can cause sleepiness and drowsiness. Hops might also cause sleepiness and drowsiness. Taking large amounts of hops along with alcohol might cause too much sleepiness.

Answer (score 0):

While this is merely anecdotal, I agree with you that beer makes me more sleepy than liquor. My theory is that perhaps it has to do with the carbohydrates (think thanksgiving dinner).